# Code Igniter with Angular 6

Tags: php, mysql, database, angular, codeigniter

I want to use Code Igniter's Controller and Model in my application that uses angular 6.

My plan is:

1. use angular 6 for the front end
2. use CI's controller to send data to Model which then sends data to database.
3. put the folders of Application(Code Igniter folder) except the view inside assets of my angular application.
4. use that controllers when I want to do database transaction.

My questions is:

1. Will this work?
2. Are there drawbacks?

Still developing my application during posting of this OP.

`auth.service` - this is called when form is submitted

```
getUserDetails(username,password){
    //post details to API server return info if correct
    return this.http.post<myData>('/api/auth.php',{
      username,
      password

    })
  }
```

this is my way to pass my data into my controller and in my controller

I should have:

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|callback_authentication');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('Home');
        }
    }
```

How should I fix `return this.http.post<myData>('/api/auth.php',{` so that I can call the function login?

Comment: totally possible. You can render the angular build using a code igniter controller.
Use API's for data communication back and forth.

Comment: @SharanMohandas my problem is in my controller. When i call in the http post like `this.http.post<myData>('/api/auth.php',{
      username,
      password

    })` how can i call the function `login(){}` in the `auth.php`?

Comment: You have to create a route in the routes.php which maps to a controller function. Then call that url from Angular

Comment: @SharanMohandas can you check my question? I updated my OP.

Comment: Why are you redirecting to Home if the validation goes well? Dummy code?

Comment: @SharanMohandas you mean to say i need to have another php file that calls the controller that  calls the model? so from my service in angular -> to the php that will call the controller then controller to model then model to database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177152/discussion-between-guradio-and-sharan-mohandas).